# Working with units in emacs calc - unable to achieve expected result

Tags: calc

I would like to calculate the following quantity:

sqrt{4kTR_S}

expressed in nV / sqrt{Hz}

(Incidentally, this site does not support math in the posts?)

In the above expression, k is Boltzmann's constant (in Joule/Kelvin), T is in Kelvin, R_S is in ohm.

To this end, I input into the calculator:

`'4*k*300*50 degK*ohm RET`

which puts:

`60000 degK k ohm`

into the `stack` as I expect.

I can then press `u c` to change the units to `V^2/Hz`, which works just fine, giving:

`8.283894e-19 V^2 / Hz`

I would now like to take the square root of this number, so just to keep the intermediate results, I just input:

`' sqrt($1)`

to get:

`sqrt(8.283894e-19 V^2 / Hz)`

as my next item to the stack.

Now, I would just like to change the units again to `nV / sqrt(Hz)`, but when I press `u c` I get the following message in the Minibuffer:

`(The expression is unitless when simplified) Old Units:`

From here on, I don't know how to proceed and what did I do wrong. I have tried many combinations but I just cannot get to the right result. Can anybody see what I could be possibly doing wrong here?

Comment: If you call algebra / simplify extended <kbd>ae</kbd>, you can continue normally with your unit conversion. Not identifying units inside the square root looks like a bug.